# How can I automatically connect to unsecured wireless networks?

Tags: wireless, connection, automatic

How can I make my Ubuntu installation automatically connect to in-range unsecured wireless networks?

Comment: What if several unsecured networks are in range?

Comment: It would probably be best to connect to the strongest one, but I would just like to know how to do this in the first place.

Comment: Any help at all would be nice.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!